# Z-index rendering bug in Chrome 19?

Tags: css, google-chrome, z-index

I have a dropdown menu on a site that was displaying correctly in all browsers including Chrome up until recently. Now in Chrome 19 it is rendered behind another element even though they both have positioning and the menu has the higher z-index.

See image of top right corner:

[image]

And here is the site:
http://www.mediaplanet.com/international/

Is this a rendering bug or is something wrong with my code?

Comment: It must be a bug. I've tested in in the Chrome developer tool, but nothing worked. Even Stackoverflow has some z-index issues with the new version. Your code seems to be Ok.

Comment: Confirmed a problem in Chrome 19. Works properly in Firefox 13 Beta.

Comment: My solution below fixes the CSS bug for Chrome 19....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `style.css` stylesheet, set a `z-index` of `9999` to `#header .row` and that should do it.

Currently it is:

```
#header .row {
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

It works for me in Chrome 19 if you change it to:

```
#header .row {
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

That should do the trick! :)

Comment: Sweeeet! Thank you so much, thought I tried every combination already, but certainly missed that one!